# Programmatically Creating TableViewControllers inside TabBarController will not render labels

Tags: ios, swift

I want to programmatically create a tabBarView with two     `tableViewControllers`

In my `AppDelegate.swift` file I added the following at the top:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let mainVC = MainTabBarController()
        window?.rootViewController = mainVC
        return true
    }
```

I have my `MainTabBarController.swift` file with the following:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit



class MainTabBarController : UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpTabBar()
    }

    func setUpTabBar() {

        let firstTableViewController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: FirstTableViewController())
        firstTableViewController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "first")
        firstViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "first-selected")

        let secondViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SecondTableViewController())
        SecondTableViewController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "second")
        SecondTableViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "second-selected")

        viewControllers = [firstViewController, SecondViewController]

        guard let items = tabBar.items else { return }
        for item in items {
            item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 0, bottom: -4, right: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

I have my `FirstTableViewController.swift` with the following:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController : UITableViewController {

    let reuseIdentifier = "firstId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        setUpNavigationBar()
        setUpTableView()
    }

    private func setUpTableView() {
        self.tableView.register(FirstTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    func setUpNavigationBar() {
        navigationItem.title = "First"

        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FirstTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

}
```

Here is `FirstTableViewCell.swift`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setUp()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let cellView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.setCellShadow()
        return view
    }()

    let firstItemLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Name"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        return label
    }()

    func setUp() {
        addSubview(cellView)
        cellView.addSubview(firstItemLabel)
    }
}
```

With this current view of `FirsTableView`, all I see is an empty tableView with no data populated even though I should be seeing `"Name"` inside every cell: https://i.stack.imgur.com/70oTi.jpg.

So I tried something different with `SecondTableViewController.swift`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SecondTableViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let reUseIdentifier: String = "secondId"

    let tableView : UITableView = {
        let tb = UITableView()
        tb.separatorStyle = .none
        tb.allowsSelection = false
        return tb
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpNavigationBar()
        setUpTableView()
    }

    func setUpNavigationBar() {
        navigationItem.title = "Second"

        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]
    }


    func setUpTableView() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(SecondTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reUseIdentifier)
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reUseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SecondTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

}
```

Where `SecondTableViewCell.swift` is very similar to `FirstTableViewCell.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class SecondTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let cellView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return view
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setUp()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setUp() {
        addSubview(cellView)
        cellView.addSubview(secondTableViewCellLabel)
    }


    let secondTableViewCellLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Name"
        label.textColor = .darkGray
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        return label
    }()
}
```

This renders nothing but a black screen with the tab name up above: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjmxL.jpg.

I'm new to creating views programmatically and I have no idea what else needs to be done to have the tabBar display both tableViews as intended.

I followed these two videos as a reference:

- [UITabBar programmatically](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVojK6sArjs)
- [UITableView programmatically](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXpRJXCJ9uA)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is rootviewcontroller set in app ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @Vinodh

Comment: In your project either you need to set intialviewcontoller in storyboard or you have set rootviewcontroller in appdelegate

Comment: Ah, updated @Vinodh

Comment: Have you put break points in the UITableViewCell init functions to see if they are being created? Also I don't see anything setting the frame size of the cells.